# Creating a loop that will run a simple regression across all Independent variables

Tags: r

I have built a simple regression model using the iris data set. I would like to run the dependent variable (`iris$Sepal.Length`) with all available variables, each regression with its own variable (each regression should be with . The outcome that I wanted to get is a list of each regression summary. Using the iris data set there should be 4 regressions:

```
r1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
r2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)
r3 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
r4 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
```

and a summary with the coefficients for each one of the regressions.
Any Ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(names(iris)[-1], 
       function(x) lm.fit(cbind(1, iris[,x]), iris[,"Sepal.Length"])$coef)
#   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species
#x1   6.5262226    4.3066034   4.7776294 4.261333
#x2  -0.2233611    0.4089223   0.8885803 0.791000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plyr)
coefs = llply(names(iris)[-1], function(x){
  fml = as.formula(sprintf("Sepal.Length ~ %s", x))
  coef(lm(fml, data = iris))
})
```