# Use broom and tidyverse to run regressions on different dependent variables

Tags: r, loops, regression, tidyverse, broom

I'm looking for a Tidyverse / broom solution that can solve this puzzle:

Let's say I have **different DVs** and a **specific** set of IVS and I want to perform a regression that considers every DV and this specific set of IVs. 
I know I can use something like for i in or apply family, but I really want to run that using *tidyverse*.

The following code works as an example

```
ds <- data.frame(income = rnorm(100, mean=1000,sd=200),
                 happiness = rnorm(100, mean = 6, sd=1),
                 health = rnorm(100, mean=20, sd = 3),
                 sex = c(0,1),
                 faculty = c(0,1,2,3))

mod1 <- lm(income ~ sex + faculty, ds)
mod2 <- lm(happiness ~ sex + faculty, ds)
mod3 <- lm(health ~ sex + faculty, ds)
summary(mod1)
summary(mod2)
summary(mod3)
```

Income, happiness, and health are DVs. Sex and Faculty are IVs and they will be used for all regressions.

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280462/creating-a-loop-that-will-run-a-simple-regression-across-all-independent-variabl?rq=1) was the closest I found

Let me know If I need to clarify my question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have different dependent variables but the same independent, you can form a matrix of these and pass to `lm`.

```
mod = lm(cbind(income, happiness, health) ~ sex + faculty, ds)
```

And I think `broom::tidy` works

```
library(broom)
tidy(mod)

#    response        term      estimate  std.error  statistic      p.value
# 1    income (Intercept) 1019.35703873 31.0922529 32.7849205 2.779199e-54
# 2    income         sex  -54.40337314 40.1399258 -1.3553431 1.784559e-01
# 3    income     faculty   19.74808081 17.9511206  1.1001030 2.740100e-01
# 4 happiness (Intercept)    5.97334562  0.1675340 35.6545278 1.505026e-57
# 5 happiness         sex    0.05345555  0.2162855  0.2471528 8.053124e-01
# 6 happiness     faculty   -0.02525431  0.0967258 -0.2610918 7.945753e-01
# 7    health (Intercept)   19.76489553  0.5412676 36.5159396 1.741411e-58
# 8    health         sex    0.32399380  0.6987735  0.4636607 6.439296e-01
# 9    health     faculty    0.10808545  0.3125010  0.3458723 7.301877e-01
```

Comment: Nice option.  I forgot about this

Comment: Thanks Akrun ... this may be my first tidyverse tagged Q ;|

Comment: You could make it `tidyverse` with `%>%`  :=)

Comment: Wow, amazing solution. @user20650  My real puzzle has different variable names and I want to know if something like this could work: j <- ds %>% select(income, happiness, health)
mod = lm(cbind(noquote(paste0(variable.names(j), collapse=","))) ~ sex + faculty, ds)

Comment: Luis ; sorry - you're asking the wrong person ;)) I don't use tidyverse syntax, perhaps@akrun can advise.

Comment: @user20650, you did an amazing job replying to my question! Thanks much! (I could run what I was looking for: j <- ds %>% select(income, happiness, health) %>% names()
fit <- lm(eval(parse(text=paste("cbind(", paste(j, collapse=","), ")"))) ~ sex + faculty, ds)
fit)

Comment: you're welcome : i suppose the non-tidy way i 'd do it is  using `vars <- c("income", "happiness", "health") ; lm(as.matrix(ds[, vars]) ~ sex + faculty, ds)` and then just change `vars` vector - but I read these days that quotes are bad

Answer (score 7):

Another method is to `gather` the dependent variables and use a grouped data frame to fit the models with `do`. This is the method explained in the broom and dplyr vignette.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
ds <- data.frame(
  income = rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 200),
  happiness = rnorm(100, mean = 6, sd = 1),
  health = rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 3),
  sex = c(0, 1),
  faculty = c(0, 1, 2, 3)
)
ds %>%
  gather(dv_name, dv_value, income:health) %>%
  group_by(dv_name) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(dv_value ~ sex + faculty, data = .)))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#> # Groups:   dv_name [3]
#>   dv_name   term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 happiness (Intercept)     6.25      0.191    32.7   3.14e-54
#> 2 happiness sex             0.163     0.246     0.663 5.09e- 1
#> 3 happiness faculty        -0.172     0.110    -1.56  1.23e- 1
#> 4 health    (Intercept)    20.1       0.524    38.4   1.95e-60
#> 5 health    sex             0.616     0.677     0.909 3.65e- 1
#> 6 health    faculty        -0.653     0.303    -2.16  3.36e- 2
#> 7 income    (Intercept)  1085.       32.8      33.0   1.43e-54
#> 8 income    sex           -12.9      42.4      -0.304 7.62e- 1
#> 9 income    faculty       -25.1      19.0      -1.32  1.89e- 1
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

We can loop through the column names that are dependent variables, use `paste` to create the `formula` to be passed into `lm` and get the summary statistics with `tidy` (from `broom`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
map(names(ds)[1:3], ~ 
            lm(formula(paste0(.x, "~", 
                paste(names(ds)[4:5], collapse=" + "))), data = ds) %>%
               tidy)
```

---

If we want it in a single `data.frame` with a column identifier for dependent variable,

```
map_df(set_names(names(ds)[1:3]), ~ 
      lm(formula(paste0(.x, "~", 
        paste(names(ds)[4:5], collapse=" + "))), data = ds) %>%
   tidy, .id = "Dep_Variable")
```

Comment: Thanks much, @akrun. You are always replying to my questions. Would you mind if I ask you how do you know so much about tidyverse and R?  Are you a data scientist? What books/material you recommend? (I always learn by trial and error as you can see =)) ) Thanks much!

Comment: @Luis Glad to answer your question.  I learned/learning R mostly through SO and R mailing list.   Your method of learning is good because getting error makes you think about the reason and it makes a deeper impression than going through the correct method.  There are lots of resources online to learn R.  May be you have gone through these [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556524/whats-the-way-to-learn-r).   Also, you can check for courses from udemy, udacity, datacamp etc.   There is no particular method that fits for all persons

Comment: Thanks again, @akrun, your replies are always very useful and informative. Best!